# JS - Stop function above current function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery click event which adds a class (`active`) to a `dropdown`.
In the `dropdown` there are boxes (with the class generically called `box`).

Currently the jQuery event fires anytime you click anywhere in the `item` class, but if you click the `box` it also closes the dropdown. Thus I am adding an if statement above the `addClass` part which checks if you clicked a `box`.

Here's the html:

```
  <div class="trainee-item">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here's the JS:

```
$('.item').click(function(e) {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    console.log('stop!!!');
  });

  if ($(this).children('.dropdown').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).children('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    return;
  }
  $(this).children('.dropdown').addClass('active');
});
```

I've tried `return` (where the `console.log('stop!!!!');` currently is, but that only stops the `$('.box').click(function()` (the immediate "parent" function). **I am trying to stop the function above that one**

Any help? thanks

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: You pretty much NEVER want to put a `.click()` handler inside another click handler because you're going to install duplicate click handlers on every click.  So, first you have to sort that is probably at least part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```
$('.item').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.className=="box"){
         e.preventDefault()
         return
    }

})
```

```js
$('.item').click(function(e) {
  
   if (e.target.className=="box"){
      e.preventDefault()
      alert("don't close it!")
      return
   }

   

  if ($(this).children('.dropdown').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).children('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    return;
  }
  $(this).children('.dropdown').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.dropdown{display:none;width:100px;height:100px;background:#bbb}
.active{height:120px;}
.item{height:20px;background:#ccc}
.active.dropdown{display:block}
.box{border-bottom:1px solid #999;padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trainee-item item">
    <div>Click me</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="box">hi</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the box also has another class say: `<div class="box other-class"><div>`

Comment: found and added `.split('')[0]` to `e.target.className` (so it's now `e.target.className.split('')[0]`)
and it works great!!! tks!

Answer (score 0):

You should separate these into separate click events. You should also delegate them, since you'll trigger both due to event bubbling. It's been a while since I've written jQuery, but from what I remember you should be using `.on();`, since you can delegate with that method.

I'll leave the [delegation as homework for you](http://api.jquery.com/on/), but here's how you should be approaching this issue:

```js
$('.item').on('click', function(e, el) {
 var $child = $(this).children('.dropdown'),
        activeClass = 'active';

 $child.hasClass(activeClass) ? $child.removeClass(activeClass) : $child.addClass(activeClass);
});

$('.box').on('click', function(e, el) {
 console.log('box clicked');
});
```